# How to avoid compatibility issue Segmentation fault (core dumped) with memory address

Tags: c

I am trying to hack the general `C` rules while research and try to store memory address in variable but my code failed with *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* when running under 64-bit system. And I know why - because of 4/8-bits (32/64-bit systems) of memory.
The question is: what primitive type (not `uintptr_t`) I need to satisfy both systems? `long long int`? My source:

```c
int main() {
    int i;

    char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

    unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;

    hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",
            hacky_nonpointer, *((char *) hacky_nonpointer));
        hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use a single fixed-size type whose size doesn't depend on whether you're building 32-bit or 64-bit? Is that why you don't want to use `uintptr_t`? If so, just use `uint64_t`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  It is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 2):

Use the appropriate pointer type:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;

    char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    char *char_pointer = char_array;

    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("[char_pointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n",
           char_pointer, *char_pointer);
        char_pointer++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know the question about how to hack with `C`)